# Large file support not working in C programming

Tags: c, large-files

I'm trying to compile a shared object (that is eventually used in Python with ctypes). The command-line used to build the object is:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -shared -Wl,-soname,borg_stream -lm -m128bit-long-double -fPIC \
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -o borg_stream.so data_stream.c data_types.c \
    file_operations.c float_half.c channels.c statistics.c index_stream.c helpers.c
```

The library builds properly on a 32-bit OS and it does what it needs to for small files. However, it fails the unit tests for files larger than 4GB. In addition, it sets errno to EOVERFLOW when doing an fseek/ftell. However, if I printf sizeof(off_t), it returns 8. If I remove `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, then it prints 4. So it seems like `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is properly doing its job.

Why does large file support still not work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could also show us some code, to help us guide you better.

Answer (score 5):

Add the option `-D_LARGE_FILE_SOURCE=1` to gcc compilation.

`fseek64()` is a C function. To make it available you'll have to define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` before including the system headers. That will more or less define `fseek` to behave as actually `fseek64`. Or you could do it in the compiler arguments e.g. `gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, that you are already doing.

http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html has a good information for large file support on linux:

Compile your programs with `gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`. This forces all file access calls to use the 64 bit variants. Several types change also, e.g. `off_t` becomes `off64_t`. It's therefore important to always use the correct types and to not use e.g. `int` instead of `off_t` in your C code. For portability with other platforms you should use `getconf      LFS_CFLAGS` which will return `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` on Linux platforms but might return something else on for e.g. on Solaris. For linking, you should use the link flags that are reported via `getconf LFS_LDFLAGS`. On Linux systems, you do not need special link flags.
Define `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`. With these defines you can use the LFS functions like `open64` directly.
Use the `O_LARGEFILE` flag with open to operate on large files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but it seems that in addition to using D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64, you need to use the fseeko/ftello instead of fseek/ftell. The man page for fseeko/ftello explicitly mentions the effect that _FILE_OFFSET_BITS has on them, but the man page for fseek/ftell makes no mention of 64-bit support.

Comment: yep. sorry. forgot to mention that you need to use seeko instead of seek and such. and you need to have LFS support to use 64-bit equivalents.

Comment: While this information is really useful, R.. actually answered the question.  Look below...

Answer (score 4):

Use fseeko and ftello. Not fseek and ftell. And certainly not any function with 64 in its name.

Comment: This was actually what fixed the problem. I was using fseek/ftell instead fseeko/ftello. Switching those functions fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

[`fseek()` and `ftell()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) take in an `int` which is 32-bit, so it is cast and you lose the ability to address space larger than 4GB. Instead use `fseeko64()` and `ftello64()` which take a `long`.