# What is the best way to seek past 2GiB in C?

Tags: c, 64-bit, stdio

There seem to be many different ways to seek in C:

- `fseek()`
- `fsetpos()`
- `fseeko()`
- `lseek()`

And many seem to have `*64()` versions:

- `fseeko64()`
- `lseek64()`

To complicate matters further many seem to require macro definitions (like `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE`) to be available or to use 64-bit versions.

What is the easiest way to guarantee 64-bit IO using ANSI C on Windows, Linux, Mac, BSD, Solaris, etc., and since when has it been supported by each OS?

Comment: Best in speed, best in compatibility, best in code simplicity?

Comment: @chux In the application I'm developing code simplicity and compatibility are my primary concerns, though any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: [Can I seek a position beyond 2GB in C using the standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30657968/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works needs to employ at least 1 of the below restriction::

1. `long` is 64-bit+, then use `fseek()`.
2. Only seek to locations that code has been to before as a result of `fread(), fgets(), fscanf(), fgets()`, and so use `fgetpos()`, `fsetpos()`.  This is the best way if the file is a text file.
3. Have access to a platform dependent 64-bit seek such as `lseek64()`.
4. Multiple 32-bit `fseek()`.
5. Use grossly inefficient code with `rewind()` and `fgetc()/fread()`.

Comment: I'm not sure about multiple 32-bit fseek()'s and fgepos()/fsetpos() may not work either (most likely both kinds of positioning functions use the same type for position and call the same OS-specific function in the end). An OS-specific function/syscall is the best bet, although, clearly not portable.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze `fgetpos()/fsetpos()` works as well on 64+ bit system as well as 32.  `fseek()` pass 4G on 32 bit systems is more tenuous.  A combo solution as you mentioned is best, using standard calls as able.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the easiest way to guarantee 64-bit IO using ANSI C on
>   Windows, Linux, Mac, BSD, Solaris, etc.

The *easiest* way?  Compile your code as a 64-bit executable.  Be sure to use proper types, e.g. `size_t` is **not** an `unsigned int` - `size_t` is `size_t`.  And hopefully, you're moved past [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89), as that generally refers to C89 and likely doesn't support 64-bit architectures well.

And as implied in the comments, there's no C Standard-compliant way to guarantee that you can easily get past 2GB.  With a 64-bit binary, though, POSIX-compliant IO (`open()`,`read()`,`write()`, etc) would all work as `size_t`/`ssize_t` used by POSIX IO is 64-bit.  POSIX also specifies [`fseeko()` and `ftello()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html#tag_13_49), which are 64-bit compliant.

> and since when has it been supported by each OS?

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_operating_system_timeline) for details.  Roughly, "full" 64-bit support dates to about the following times:

- Solaris: 1998
- Linux: 2003
- Windows: 2006
- OS X: 2007

Comment: The `fseek()` function defined by standard C passes `offset` as `long`, though, and depending on the [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) (e.g. Windows uses LLP64), `long` may not be 64-bits; this is where the 2GiB limitation comes from (`LONG_MAX` must be at least (2^31)-1).

Comment: @oopaewem Thanks for pointing that out, but the OP did ask for the *easiest* way.  In that case, you're back to the link from Lưu Vĩnh Phúc in his comment above (that there's no C Standard-compliant way):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657968/can-i-seek-a-position-beyond-2gb-in-c-using-the-standard-library.

Comment: I saw that link, and I suppose my OP is slightly misleading. By ANSI C I didn't mean I wanted to use exclusilevy ANSI C and no other (possibly platform dependent) libraries, I just meant to say I didn't want to use any C99 or C11 features, since Microsoft still doesn't have a complete C99 compiler (nor do they plan to). That said, C11 doesn't appear to have any standard way for seeking past 2GiB on an LLP64 data model either, so this is kind of a moot point.

Comment: @oopaewem  POSIX seems to be the only standard that explicitly addresses 64-bit issues.  http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html